# UWP nativemessaging host print to network printer using sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, printing, uwp, network-printers

We are trying to build an UWP app with native messaging where the user will print labels on their network printers. Here is the code

```
string printerIPAddress = msg.ipAddress;
int printerPort = msg.port;
IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(printerIPAddress);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(addr, printerPort);
Socket clientSock = 
new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
byte[] zplBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((string)msg.zplText);
clientSock.Connect(remoteEP);
var bytesSent = clientSock.Send(zplBytes, zplBytes.Length, 0);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception thrown:
'System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException'
in System.Net.Sockets.dll
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException:
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

We have built similar native messaging app for chrome and FF and we can print using network printer without any issue.

Comment: Have you enabled this capbility "Private Networks (Client & Server)." from your app? Also have you tried to use UWP Socket API instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking

Comment: Yes, I did enable the network capabilities in my app. Thanks for the link I will check if I can work in that route.

Comment: Thanks Barry Wang!! I went and looked again for network capabilities and they were not enabled in correct place.. Once I changed it, it started working correctly.